# Methods to find IP Address?

Tags: ip

I'm currently exploring methods of recon and discovery on my Metasploitable 2 and Kali Linux VM environment. I've worked with nmap scans which is great if you are connected to a specific network and understand your target, but I would like to change my Metasploitable 2 server to a different IP subnet than my Kali VM, i.e. simulating a different network.

How would I scan/search/look for my Metasploitable IP going in blind and simulating a unknown pen test? I would need to make some sort of connection, eg: ping or packet trace.

Is this even possible? What actions, risks, connection would my Metasploitable server have to take in order to leave a trace/IP.

Comment: This is more of a basic networking question.

Comment: Not really. I'm asking a specific question related to the reconnaissance phase of a controlled pen test.